# Datatable bulk copy to SQL Server merge row id

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using the code below for insert data from a datatable into SQL Server. My question is if there is any way to merge rows. If id not exist insert, else update.

```
using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
{
    try
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TableName;
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bulkcopy to a temporary table, update based on join to temporary table, insert where not exists and then truncate the temporary table.

Comment: No you cannot do update with `BulkCopy`. What you can do is to bulk copy into a staging table and then run a stored procedure and use `Merge` to upset into the final table.

Comment: Consider using a table-valued parameter with your DataTable value and use it in a `MERGE` statement.

Comment: Thank you Dan. Is there any way to create a new TempTable without from my bulkCopy Datatable? Without to define column names?

Comment: A TVP is a temp table under the covers but it requires defining a table type. I'll elaborate with an answer.

Comment: Dan one more question. I need to create a database syncronization. That's my final purpose. Two databases with the same tables. The problem is the identity key. I need both of my databases to be local. And to synchronise with their data each other.

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΧριστοφορίδης, conditional insert/updates cannot be done with a surrogate key (identity). You'll need match on a natural key or truncate and reload.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use EFC for such things, its easy to handle bulk operations with pseudo objects. You can read about entity framework core bulk operations here : https://dotnetdetail.net/entity-framework-core-3-0-bulk-insert-update-and-delete/

Comment: A post which is just a link to elsewhere is not an answer - it is a note about where the answer is.  This could be a comment.

Comment: I just started commenting, did not realize it :)  no problems, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have better solution and approach to achieve this..  which will be very fast and response time will be very very less.

Answer (score 0):

A table-valued parameter with your DataTable value can be used in a `MERGE` statement for conditional `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. Create a table type that matches your `DataTable` schema, e.g.:

```
CREATE TYPE TvpType AS TABLE(
      ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , DataValue int
);
```

Then pass the `DataTable` as a parameter of type `SqlDbType.Structured` to the `MERGE` statement:

```
string mergeStatement = @"
MERGE dbo.YourTable AS target
USING @TVP AS source ON source.ID = target.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET DataValue = source.DataValue
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (ID, DataValue) VALUES(source.ID, source.DataValue);";

try
{
    using (SqlCommand mergeCommand = new SqlCommand(mergeStatement, connection))
    {
        mergeCommand.Parameters.Add("@TVP", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt;
        mergeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
```